# How do I make my events fire only once if true rather than for every update iteration?

Tags: lua

My event listener code is as follows:

```
local events = {}

function registerEvent (event)
    table.insert(events, event)
end

function unregisterEvent (event)
    table.remove(events, event)
end

function processEvents ()
    for _, event in pairs(events) do
        for _, condition in pairs(event.conditions) do
            if condition() then
                event.triggered = true;
            else
                event.triggered = false;
                break
            end
        end

        if event.triggered then
            event.callback()
        end
    end
end

registerEvent
{
    conditions = {
        function () return Keyboard.Shift == true end
    },
    callback = function () text = "triggered" end
}

registerEvent
{
    conditions = {
        function () return Keyboard.Shift == false end
    },
    callback = function () text = "not triggered" end
}
```

The update loop code is simply:

```
function OnUpdate(deltaTime)
    processEvents()
end
```

Basically what I want is for the callback to trigger only once when the conditions are true, rather than for every additional update (and then for the firing check to reset when the condition isn't true).

Comment: It sounds like your keyboard state isn't getting reset at the end of the frame. Is there code that manages your keyboard?

Comment: It actually is updating but the main problem is that I only want it to fire on the first frame that the conditions are met, rather than for every frame that they are met.

Comment: Can you add a variable that tracks if a variable was ever triggered, and then just not call it again once that's set to true? e.g. `if event.triggered and not event.triggeredbefore then event.callback() event.triggeredbefore = true end`

Comment: I can, could you give me a code example? I'm dealing with some crazy tunnel vision for something that should be so simple.

Comment: I just did. Replace the code `if event.triggered then event.callback() end` with the code I just gave you.

Comment: This works except that I'm unable to trigger it again when I need to. I don't want to lock it out forever but only if it would be triggered directly after it was already.

Comment: So set triggeredbefore to false again. e.g. `if condition() then event.triggered = true; else event.triggered = false; event.triggeredbefore = false break end`

Comment: Excellent. If you wouldn't mind making an official answer, please do so that I may credit you for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, you can make this work the way you want with the following modifications to your `processEvents`:

```
function processEvents ()
    for _, event in pairs(events) do
        for _, condition in pairs(event.conditions) do
            if condition() then
                event.triggered = true;
            else
                event.triggered = false;
                event.triggeredbefore = false
                break
            end
        end

        if event.triggered and not event.triggeredbefore then
            event.callback()
            event.triggeredbefore = true
        end
    end
end
```